# Splitting a string within a cell by searching for multiple words?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Similar to this,

```
=RIGHT([@LinkToSharepointList],LEN([@LinkToSharepointList])-FIND("word1",[@LinkToSharepointList]))
```

But allowing for word1, word2, word3, etc..

The data looks like

```
"https://sharepoint/sites/folder_name/this_is_a_long_word1 01.02.2020.xlsx"
"https://sharepoint/sites/folder_name/this_is_a_long_word3 01 02 2020.xlsx"
"https://sharepoint/sites/folder_name/this_is_a_long 01022020.xlsx"
```

I'm trying to return the date, thanks

Comment: What is the result you're looking for?  Can you provide an example of an input cell and the expected result?

Comment: Without Data Example this is a shot in the dark, but check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7 and check VBA Split https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Thanks, editing the question to show the data

Comment: Something like `=MID(A2,SEARCH(" ??.??.????.xlsx",A2)+1,10)` maybe?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the date isn't always in the same format, e.e. 010202020, 01 02 2020, 01.02.2020, etc..

Comment: That's very relevant information you should mention in the body of your question. Also, let us know if it's always at then end **and** if the extension is always ".xlsx".

Comment: Thanks, it is always a .xlsx, the date is always at the end from the data I see, but to be safe, I'd like to split by "word1", "word2", rather than a character count from the end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- The date is made up out of the 8 rightmost digits;
- You are using ms365;
- Your local settings would recognize a date formatted like "dd-mm-yyyy" or "mm-dd-yyyy").

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(--RIGHT(CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),"")),8),"00-00-0000"))
```

Comment: Sir, i tried this one, but not sure it looks messy, **`=TEXT(MAX(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1," ",1),".xlsx"),{" ","."},""),"")),"00\/00\/0000")*1`**

Comment: Yeah @MayukhBhattacharya, since OP was not sure about all possible formats (hence the *"etc...*" I went with a simpler approach to just return the last 8 digits.